# Android Studio syncing failed

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

When I am trying to upgrade my gradle in Android studio it is not able to download few dependencies. Android Studio version is 3.3.1.

I right clicked on my project then Flutter -> Open Android module in Android Studio. It opened a new window and started syncing process. but few of them were not downloaded.

I also tried solution Settings -> Build … -> Gradle -> Android Studio -> Enable embedded maven repository but it did not worked for me.

As it is my home computer I do not suspect any proxy issue or such..

[image]

Below is my android/**build.gradle** file.
[image: android/build.gradle]

Has anyone faced this issue?

Thank you

Comment: What is the error given for those failed downloads? I.e. if you click on the red circle with an exclamation point, what error message appears on the right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have edited the question with error description.

Comment: Looks like you are having some problem with the internet. It shows the download is failing.

Comment: do not add code as image!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply! I tried after disabling the McAfree Real time scanning and Firewall but it still not working...

Comment: Can you try upgrading your version of firebase?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska you mean the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file? or something else?

Comment: @Sam I'm not familiar with flutter. In general in an android project it should be in the build.gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re installing the Android studio the problem disappeared...

Answer (score 0):

This Could be caused by gradle offline settings. Uncheck Gradle work offline in Settings. 
Then Connect PC to the internet and sync again. I think your problem will be solved. If any further issues please add your `build.gradle` file in the description.

Comment: Hi just checked for the offline mode but it is not offline. I have also added the android/build.gradle file in the question. Thanks for your time!